# Codeigniter Model array MAX ID

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, model, max

I need to get array `MAX ID` from column `pr_id` at my `pr_data` table. Here's my code what I have tried so far.

```
public function get_id_max($id) {
    $this->db->select_max(array('pr_id' => $id));
    $query = $this->db->get('pr_data');
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this:  

 $this->db->select_max('pr_id');
    $this->db->where('pr_id', $id);
    $result = $this->db->get('pr_data');
return $query->row_array();
```